# Run pageMod in background thread in firefox addon sdk?

Tags: highlighting, background-process, firefox-addon-sdk

I have to make a firefox addon that searches the loaded page against a list of words (potentially 6500 words) and highlight matches and show synonyms on hover.

So i am using [HightlightRegex.js](https://github.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex/blob/master/highlightRegex.js) that traverses the dom and searches based on a regex which is using the regex **\bMyWord\b**.

The main problem is when testing the addon on a page that has many occurrences of the search word, Firefox hangs for a while (5-6 sec) and then highlights are shown. This is happening for 1 word so one can just imagine what will happen if i search 6500 words.

So is there any way that i can run the [pageMod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/page-mod.html) in a background thread or asynchronously and highlight words as they are matched without freezing the UI?

You can have a look at the add-on at https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1042263/latest/

Currently the add-on is not tied to separate tabs and run as a whole on the browser but i doubt that would cause Firefox to hang.

I need to do this as efficiently as possible so suggestion are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is generally not thread-safe and you cannot access it from anything other than the main thread. The only solution would be breaking up the work into smaller chunks and using `setTimeout(..., 0)` to run next chunk asynchronously, without blocking everything.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more? even if i run the search in a setTimeout wouldn't that block while the set timeout function is running. a simple example to explain the point would be very helpful.

Comment: @PankajKumar: Yes, it will block - which is why only a small chunk should be processed in a single timeout. Then it should call `setTimeout()` and allow the browser to process events before the next chunk is processed.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is useing the page-worker module to load the page and process it:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/packages/addon-kit/page-worker.html

And, as Wladimir suggested, only use asynchronous code to search the document text to avoid locking up firefox.

Answer (score 1):

As canuckistani hinted, the better solution requires only two synced DOM operations: reading and writing. Rip the entire page (or, even better, only its `<body>`) and send it through to an async worker or thread which will perform the highlighting. When it's done, the worker emits an event and passes the highlighted content, which the addon can now insert back into the page.

That way, the only synchronous operations done are fast, inexpensive ones, while the rest is done asynchronously, away from the main thread. However, canuckistani suggested to load the page in a `page-worker`: there is no need to do that, as the page is already loaded in a tab. Just load up a fake page and insert the actual content.